# Can't start PyPy Windows: Library path not found

Tags: pypy

I have PyPy v1.9 installed on Windows 8, 64-bit. I added the folder that has the pypy.exe binary to my path (C:\Users\me\Documents\pypy-1.9), but when I try to run PyPy I get the following error message:

> debug: WARNING: Library path not found, using compiled-in sys.path
>
> debug: WARNING: 'sys.prefix' will not be set.
>
> debug: WARNING: Make sure the pypy binary is kept inside its tree of files.
>
> debug: WARNING: It is ok to create a symlink to it from somewhere else.
>
> 'import site' failed
>
> Python 2.7.2 (341e1e3821ff, Jun 07 2012, 15:43:00)
>
> [PyPy 1.9.0 with MSC v.1500 32 bit] on win32
>
> Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for information.
>
> debug: OperationError: debug:
>
> operror-type: ImportError
>
> debug:  operror-value: No module named _pypy_interact

This only happens when attempting to run PyPy outside of the directory it lives in. If I run the exe directly, a command prompt will open up and run correctly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm still not sure why this is happening, but I did find a solution of a sorts. I took a little time to create a very simple batch file with the same name as the pypy executable (pypy.bat) in the folder that normally holds pypy.exe, and renamed pypy.exe to pypy_binary.exe (or whatever else, it doesn't actually matter). On top of this, I put in a slightly hacky workaround to getting the directory set to where the file I am running is: passing it as an argument to the script. I then check for an argument, and change to the directory provided (os.chdir(sys.argv[1])).

Here is the batch file for any further people who might have this issue:

```
@echo off
set LAST=%CD%
pushd %~dp0
echo %LAST% > last.tmp
if "%1" == "" goto noargs

start /B /WAIT pypy_binary.exe "%LAST%\%1" "%LAST%"
goto finish

:noargs
start /B /WAIT pypy_binary.exe

:finish
popd
```

As a slight side note: if you're using pypy to run a program that uses pyglet, you will need to edit 'pyglet/libs/win32/**__*init*__**.py' lines 192 to 196 (approx.). Under pypy, tuple does not have an **__itemsize___** attribute, and so you will need to either put in a try/except, or just set '_user32.SetClassLongPtrW = _user32.SetClassLongW' directly without having an if/else.